# Can I distribute the data from one machine and have this data be read from all nodes in the cluster?

Tags: cluster-computing, ignite

We have to work with some Global Parameters.  We want to calculate these parameters on one machine and distribute them to the Ignite Cluster, can we do this?

According to the guidance of the official website, Ignite is an distributed clustering which has no master or slaver or standby.

By the way, we need to use the ignite lightly first, we will use it as a Spring's bean in our Distributed System.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to just one node work, and all the nodes have replicated data and can be read.  Oh, I think maybe this way can work:     <bean class="org.apache.ignite.services.ServiceConfiguration">
          <property name="name" value="myCounterService"/>
          <property name="maxPerNodeCount" value="1"/>

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that easily with a REPLICATED Ignite cache. Every value that you put to that cache will be copied to all other nodes in cluster. Data won't be lost while at least one node still runs.

Here is some [documentation on cache modes](http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/v1.7/docs/cache-modes).